# Google Play Publish Upload Failed

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an app on Google Play Store and I want to make an update (same app, new apk with new version). The version I had before is 1.0.9.0 and the version and the one I'm trying to upload is 1.1.0.0. Here's the error message:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: this question implicates that you can't read ... in the error there are all informations to resolve the problem ... do you know that there is a difference between "name" and "code"

Comment: @Selvin very funny...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.package.name"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="1.1">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
</application>
```

version code 2 will fix... make sure you save and rezip before upload to play

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the version number in the app you are trying to publish

Answer (score 0):

> **android:versionCode** — An integer value that represents the version of
>   the application code, relative to other versions.
>
> The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it,
>   for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set
>   the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that
>   each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative.
>
> Typically,you would release the first version of your application with
>   versionCode set to 1, then
>   monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether
>   the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the
>   **android:versionCode** value does not necessarily have a strong
>   resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the
>   user (see android:versionName, below). Applications and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.

https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html